Not able to change the color of btn text on hover when using the variations theme
The following CSS changes a btn background color but not the text color.  What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
  /* Change button color and background on hover */
  .wp-element-button:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }

Here is the HTML that the Variation Theme generates for a btn
<div class="wp-block-button has-custom-font-size is-style-fill mybtn has-small-font-size"><a class="wp-block-button__link has-text-color has-link-color has-border-color wp-element-button" style="border-color:#ff0000;border-style:solid;border-width:2px;border-radius:0px;color:#ff0000;padding-top:5px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:10px">LEARN MORE</a></div>


Looks like you might be overriding the class style with your inline style. Is the text color showing as color:#ff0000?

The color is defined in the html style="" which has way higher specificity than any CSS. If you cannot modify the html, then the only way is to use color: white !important; in your CSS.

Try using the !important flag. Since WP may have default styles, you may want to overwrite them
 .wp-element-button:hover {
    background-color: red !important;
    color: white !important;
  }


Thank you, thank you.  I tried "!important" before with no luck ...... I mistakenly put it after the the semi-colon

Glad it worked! Can you mark my answer as correct so you can help me contribute more with the community? Thanks a lot :)

You can try this.
This basically overrides any default rules created by WordPress
/* Change button color and background on hover */
.wp-element-button:hover {
    background-color: red !important; /* Use !important to ensure the property overrides any conflicting rules */
    color: white !important;
}

